# New MBP 13" can't connect to external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

I am trying to connect my oldish LG monitor with DVI port (adapter hdmi to dvi is in monitors end) to my macbook pro 13" (late 2013 haswell model)

and it is pretty weird, macbook recognizes monitors model, I can change resolution, even hertz rate is correct- 59hz, but monitor just says to check cable. Cable is fine, it was working with my windows laptop, it is working with friends windows laptop.

what I have tried, checked all posibilieties that monitor or cable could be damaged, and walked through all settings on mac, can't get it work.

Comment: not sure but i think some HDMI DVI connectors are directional.    Have only used them from source side in pat.  http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=172798  asserts that this is not the case.   Even if it shuold work, Apple seems to have some "sensing" on their ports which might be fooled by the adaptor.

Comment: I contacted support, and they said that adapter might work and might not work, in generaly they are not suported on mac

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the external monitor to display when I used an HDMI to DVI cable.

HDMI output from MacBook, DVI input on the LG monitor.

I have and LG 27 inch monitor